# How can I use a Java library that has a .to method in Kotlin as it assumes I mean to use the infix operator for creating a pair

Tags: java, kotlin, mailgun, language-interoperability

I am using the Mailgun Java API which is used to send emails. There is a `.to` method on a message builder that you use to populate the recipient's details. However, when I try to use this it tells me that there is a compilation error as it assumes I am trying to use the `.to` function that creates a pair.

I started with:

```
Message.builder()
    .from(emailAddress)
    .subject(subject)
    .attachment(File("/path/to/file"))
    .to(recipient)
    .build()
```

It tells me `.build()` is an Unresolved Reference and when I hover over `.to` it shows

```
public infix fun <A, B> A.to(
    that: B
): Pair<A, B>
```

as the function it is using. I tried to specify `` .`to`(recipient) `` in order to try to get around this and tried to see if I could import the method but this is not possible and I removed this as it tells me

> Cannot import 'to', functions and properties can be imported only from packages or objects

I also tried creating an extension function but it can't access the private `to` property of the MessageBuilder so this doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you pass the right type of value for the `recipient`, the `to` function from the `MessageBuilder` *will* be called instead of the standard library function that creates pairs. Member functions take precedence over extension functions.

If your code appears to be incorrectly using the standard library `to` function that builds a `Pair`, it could mean that your `recipient` value is the wrong type. When there are multiple functions to choose from, overloads are resolved by looking at the compile-type type of their arguments.

For example, this doesn't work, because the `MessageBuilder.to` function doesn't accept an argument of type `Any`:

```kotlin
val recipient: Any = "hello@example.com"
Message.builder()
    .to(recipient) // picks the wrong function
    .build()       // doesn't compile
```

But passing a `String` allows the compiler to choose the correct function.

```kotlin
val recipient: String = "hello@example.com"
Message.builder()
    .to(recipient)
    .build()
```

Comment: yes, you are correct, thanks! I had an incorrect type in the `.to()` function but the compiler/ide ended up showing this in a confusing way as it doesn't acknowledge the fact i have provided the wrong argument because it can compile with the Tuples' `.to` function. Interesting/good to know that member functions do have precedence over extensions which makes sense